x-www-form-urlencoded POST requests in Spring Boot 2.7.18
The next snippet is from a project that has been working on Spring Boot v1.5.6, but it has recently been upgraded to Spring Boot v2.7.18 (along with other dependencies)
It represents the endpoint to which Redsys sends responses after a purchase intent and it has always worked fine, but it does not anymore since the upgrade.
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity postRequestResponse(
    @RequestParam long store_id,
    @RequestParam String Ds_MerchantParameters,
    @RequestParam String Ds_Signature
) {
    try {
        new PaymentPlatformBL().insertCompraRedsysResponse(
            store_id, Ds_MerchantParameters, Ds_Signature
        );
    } catch (SmartException e) {
        // exception handling
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // exception handling
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
}

Apparently Redsys sends the params in x-www-form-urlencoded body type.
After performing some basic testing via Postman and curl command, it looks like the parameters reach the application as it is clearly displayed in the next log:
LoggingFilter : [SERVICE ENTRY] [POST] /payment/purchase/redsys store_id=1&Ds_MerchantParameters=ABCD&Ds_Signature=EFGH
Those are obviously random values, which are being printed by a class annotated with @WebFilter.
However those keys are not being found/bind in the PostMapping method. This is also displayed as an error in the log as: required parameter 'store_id' not found.
We currently did some workaround which works but we do not like at all. It consists in some sort of manual parameters parsing:
public ResponseEntity postRequestResponse(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

    ...
    LoggingFilter.BufferedRequestWrapper bufferedRequest = new LoggingFilter.BufferedRequestWrapper(request);
    String requestBody = bufferedRequest.getRequestBody();
    ...
    Map<String, String> reqBodyParams = new HashMap<>();
    String[] pairs = requestBody.split("&");
    for (String pair : pairs) {
        int idx = pair.indexOf("=");
        String key = URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(0, idx), "UTF-8");
        String value = URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(idx + 1), "UTF-8");
        reqBodyParams.put(key, value);
    }
    ...
}

